# How to create a custom measure?

Tags: powerbi

I need each column to use the function below. The values ​​of each column entered into the VN and changed automatically with this formula below:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to use DAX, but I'm kind of lost on how to apply this custom formula to EVERY column and their respective values.

Remembering that the calculation in this formula personalizes is for EVERY value of the respective column, and replacement of the new phrases generated in the formula.

**Example:**

The formula should be used in the entire column and in all columns, however in this example I will do in a column and row only ..I am using for example the "Correlation (MIN)" column in line 1:

**R= (3.5 + 1543) / 2.380.849 = 6,50**

Then the new value in this row and column will be replaced by 6.50 and so on in all columns separately from this column and then the same for the other columns.

[image]

Comment: Please show your data, and show your desired outcome. Otherwise, I have no idea what your question means.

Comment: @RADO LOOK NOW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning, if I understood you correctly the following DAX will work:

```
Column R Transformation :=
VAR Numerator = ( 'Table'[Column] + 1543 )
VAR Denominator = 2380849
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( Numerator, Denominator ) )
```

You can create a calculated column to transform each original column; just change the 'Table'[Column] part in the measure accordingly.